# RefreshID = setinterval not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm building a weather data live website, using a template kindly donated to me. It's supposed to refresh the element data every 5 seconds or whatever I set but in every browser I'm having to refresh or force refresh or even delete all history, cookies, etc. to get the latest data. I don't really want to refresh the whole page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     windspeed();
});

function windspeed() {
    $('#windspeed').load('windspeed.php');
}
var refreshId = setInterval(windspeed, 5000);
```

Comment: I have tried to use the four space rule for the code posting here but the forum software does not want to post my code.....

Comment: No, you haven't tried to use four-space rule. Look, I *did* use that and it worked.

Comment: really sorry but i tried the 4 space and also ctrl+k and i could not get it to work, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: you're doing multiple url requests in the same time because you're using `setInterval`. Use `setTimeout` instead, but only when the url request finish.

You've to replace the `.load` method by `$.ajax` because it has the success callback:

```
var refreshId;

$(document).ready(function() {
    windspeed();
});

function windspeed() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#windspeed').html(response);
            setTimeout(windspeed, 5000);
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'windspeed.php'
    });
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your code, unfortunately I have realised that I probably have to alter other code elsewhere to work with this updated code and I probably dont know where to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works !!! Thank you so much. You had 2 typos with 'windspeed' as in 'winspeed', not surprising considering how fast you typed it. Thank you, I will share this with others using the same weather station template. You have made my day, no, actually you have made my whole week.

Thanks a million.